# Update column value with diiferent condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

1) I want to update value from column "Order_name" from table 'Orders" after checking some condition (Area, Condition_flag)

Example:

```
when Area='1' and Condition_flag=C then Order_name= 'Num_Order'+'_'+'Condition_flag'
```

2) Update Store_code `when Area ='2' and Condition_flag='T'`

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: Google `UPDATE FROM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may fulfill your both requirements

```
UPDATE t SET 
    Order_name = CASE WHEN t.Area='1' and t.Condition_flag = 'C' THEN CONCAT(Num_Order, '-', Condition_flag) ELSE  Order_name END,
    Store_code = CASE WHEN t.Area='2' and t.Condition_flag = 'T' THEN 'Value Goes Here' ELSE  Store_code END
FROM #TableName t
WHERE t.area IN ('1','2')
    AND t.condition_flag IN ('c', 't')
```

but please adjust values if integer then quote not required otherwise is must be.

Answer (score 0):

Try as the below:

```
update Orders 
set  Order_name = Num_Order+'_'+Condition_flag  
where 
     Area='1' and Condition_flag='C'
```

Comment: Many case so need to use Case?